# synchronization through EventWaitHandle not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, event-wait-handle

so basically this is the code I've been testing

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = 0;

    EventWaitHandle calcDone = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((x) => { result += GetNumer(); calcDone.Set(); });

    var result2 = 15;

    calcDone.WaitOne();

    result += result2;

    Console.WriteLine(result2);
}

static int GetNumer()
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    return 2000;
}
```

so basically you would expect 2015 to be written in console windows but no, just 15 is output. `WaitOne` is working OK because until the `GetNumber` returns and increments the result the execution is stopped but afterwards I don't know what happens. If you just debug the code and ho step by step everything is OK but if you just run the code it outputs 15. Am I doing something wrong here ? please don't ask why am I using thread pools and not tasks. it's just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only line of code that changes your "result2" variable is `var result2 = 15;`. After that, `result2` remains 15 while you're incrementing your `result` variable.

P.S. Excellent illustration why you shouldn't name your variables like "result2" or "variable4".

Comment: oooh. I should be outputting result. :/ thanks